# Confused about Yolov4

Tags: algorithm, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

Based on yolov4 paper(https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.10934.pdf) : yolov4 model consist of these components:
•   Input: Image, Patches, Image Pyramid
•   Neck:SPP or PAN.
•   Backbone: CSPDarknet53
•   Heads:
o   Dense Prediction (one-stage): (YOLOv3).

I am wondering how to use yolov3 entire model as a part of yolov4(in the Heads component), I mean when the author of the paper used yolov3 word, does he mean a specific part of yolov3, or he means the entire model of yolov3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the head architecture of yolov4 is the same as yolov3